# Passing data in functions, doing it wrong?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm using Corona SDK to create an Android/iOS app. And I'm trying to pass two different parameters in a function. The function is called like this:

```
function onCollision( self, event )
```

The problem is, when the function is called, it returns this error: `attempt to index local "event" a nil value`. I know why, I think it's because of the comma. But I've read documentation and that's how you're supposed to do it, any help?

Comment: Simply try `function onCollision( event )`. Also, [read this](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/physics/collisionDetection/index.html) page thoroughly!

Answer (score 1):

If you give a table object and reference your function as part of the table it should work:

```
local object = display.newImage( "object.png" )
physics.addBody( object , { ... } )

local function onCollision( self, event )
    ...
end

object.collision = onCollision
object:addEventListener( "collision", object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be function onCollision(event), self isn't needed.

If you actually want to pass another parameter to this function, you can do it using a closure like that:

```
local myParam = 1
Runtime:addEventListener ( "collision", function(event) 
                                         return onCollision(event, myParam) 
                                        end )
```